# [MS Graph]: Handling special characters in string search in a MS graph query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am searching for an object with a display name. MS graph throws an exception if it contains & or # withing the search string. Is there a way around this??

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?$filter=displayName eq 'application # manager'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL encoding the '#' in the request.

For example below request will help you in querying 'application # manager',

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=displayName eq 'application%20%23%20manager'
```

For more details look in to Output in my environment below:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you... Is there a document somewhere we can see what special characters aren't allowed? For example & also isn't.

Comment: UrlEncoding will do what you are requested here.please go through [urlencoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.httpencoder.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8) as a dot net sample